# Fazer aplicação Java rodar como Serviço

Tags: java, windows

Tenho uma aplicação Java e gostaria que a mesma rode como um serviço no Windows. 
Pesquisei na net e vi algumas formas de fazer sendo algumas mais práticas e outras meio confusas. 
Alguém que já tenha feito algo do tipo poderia indicar qual caminho utilizou?

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não dá para fazer uma aplicação Java rodar como serviço no Windows utilizando apenas Java.

Você terá que fazer uma outra aplicação, em outra linguagem (.Net, C++...) encapsulando a sua. Esta outra aplicação é que vai rodar como serviço e vai gerenciar a execução da sua aplicação em Java.

Se você tiver opção de usar uma ferramenta de terceiros (que nem sempre é de graça), eu já usei esta aqui e recomendo porque é flexível, funciona muito bem e poupa bastante mão de obra sua: [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html).